# Maintain relations via foreign key when appending data to tables with autoincrement

Tags: pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Suppose I successively get two pandas data frames, `df_base` and `df_referencing`. Both have the standard numeric index with values `0,1,2,...`. `df_referencing` has a column `base_id` which refers to the index of `df_base` -- in database terms, this would be the foreign key.

Each time I get these new data frames, I want to append them to the corresponding sqlite table

```
CREATE TABLE base_table (
  "ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "COL1" FLOAT,
  "COL2" FLOAT);

CREATE TABLE referencing_table (
  "ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "COL1" FLOAT,
  "COL2" FLOAT,
  "BASE_ID" INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(BASE_ID) REFERENCES base_table(ID));
```

I have the following two questions:

- How do I insert both `df_base` and `df_referencing` such that the primary key will be continued from the existing records onwards? I can't get it to work with the pandas method `to_sql`. Do I have to write my own sql command, e.g. `INSERT INTO base_table (COL1, COL2) VALUES ('0.736252', '0.709897');` which will create the `ID` value automatically? [*Answered the question myself in Edit 1*]
- How can I make sure that the foreign key in table `referencing_table` is updated using the primary key to be created upon insertion into table `base_table`?

My environment: Windows 10, python 3.7.0, pandas 0.24.0, sqlalchemy 1.2.16

Maybe it helps to look at example dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_base = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2), columns = ['COL1', 'COL2'])
df_referencing = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2), columns = ['COL1', 'COL2'])
df_referencing['base_id'] = [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]
print(df_base)
print(df_referencing)

# df_base
       COL1      COL2
0  0.736252  0.709897
1  0.846635  0.372465
2  0.360253  0.302076
3  0.695931  0.407356
4  0.800489  0.070650

# df_referencing
       COL1      COL2  base_id
0  0.529504  0.951910        0
1  0.407145  0.321576        0
2  0.685721  0.488690        1
3  0.943426  0.961819        1
4  0.355398  0.299547        2
5  0.118759  0.234632        2
6  0.243048  0.585558        3
7  0.117997  0.957484        3
8  0.792215  0.596002        4
9  0.265951  0.656986        4
```

Edit 1:

I have to correct myself: `to_sql` respects the `AUTOINCREMENT` property if I pass `index=False`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy
import os

# create sample data
df_base = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2), columns = ['COL1', 'COL2'])
df_referencing = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2), columns = ['COL1', 'COL2'])
df_referencing['base_id'] = [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]
print(df_base)
print(df_referencing)

# establish connection
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:////'+os.getcwd()+'test.db')

# write to db
df_base.to_sql('base_table', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
df_base_read = pd.read_sql_table('base_table', con=engine)
print(df_base_read)
```

Comment: did you try `df_base.to_sql('base_table', connection, index_label='id')` and  `df_referencing.to_sql('referencing_table', connection, index_label='id')`

Comment: I have not because it would mess up the indexes the second time I try to append the dataframes, right? That is the the second time I append `df_base` and `df_referencing` there are already records of those exact same indexes. Hence, I expect to get a conflict with the PRIMARY KEY property.

Comment: @jhonnny yes it would not work like this, if you want to stick to pandas the only solution I see is you pulling the current based_table, append it to df, then increment the last index. If I were you I would learn to map SQL tables and use the sql alchemy ORM

Comment: @StevenG Pulling the entire current `df_base` is not feasible because my database will have several million records. I don't want to seem lazy, but could you please elaborate on your suggestion? I don't have to stick to pandas as long as the data ends up where it should. One inelegant way I thought of was to query the largest `N` values of the ID field where `N` is the number of records I appended before (which I know) and then construct the updated `base_id` by using the `df_base`-based values of column `base_id` as the index for looking up the new id.